# Time Zone Differences in converted timestamp

Tags: php, sql, datetime, timestamp, unix-timestamp

I've got this class I found for converting timestamps to X Time Ago.
It works great, except for one problem. I'm in the Pacific Time Zone, and so the time always says 8 hours ago, when it should really say 2 seconds ago.

```
    class Cokidoo_DateTime extends DateTime {
        protected $strings = array(
            'y' => array('1 year ago', '%d years ago'),
            'm' => array('1 month ago', '%d months ago'),
            'd' => array('1 day ago', '%d days ago'),
            'h' => array('1 hour ago', '%d hours ago'),
            'i' => array('1 minute ago', '%d minutes ago'),
            's' => array('now', '%d secons ago'),
        );

        /**
         * Returns the difference from the current time in the format X time ago
         * @return string
         */
        public function __toString() {
            $now = new DateTime('now');
            $diff = $this->diff($now);

            foreach($this->strings as $key => $value){
                if( ($text = $this->getDiffText($key, $diff)) ){
                    return $text;
                }
            }
            return '';
        }

        /**
         * Try to construct the time diff text with the specified interval key
         * @param string $intervalKey A value of: [y,m,d,h,i,s]
         * @param DateInterval $diff
         * @return string|null
         */
        protected function getDiffText($intervalKey, $diff){
            $pluralKey = 1;
            $value = $diff->$intervalKey;
            if($value > 0){
                if($value < 2){
                    $pluralKey = 0;
                }
                return sprintf($this->strings[$intervalKey][$pluralKey], $value);
            }
            return null;
        }
    }
```

How I insert new rows via SQL:

```
    mysql_query("INSERT INTO `" . $dbMain . "`.`" . $dbTable . "` (`title`, `date`) VALUES ('$fileTitle', NOW())");
```

Default is set to CURRENT_TIMESTAMP;

How can I modify my method to get this to work?
Ideally, I'd like this to be universal for everyone, so no matter what time zone you're in, it will shows X time ago based on when a new entry is in existence.

Comment: Are the timestamps in local time or UTC?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
        $now = new DateTime('now');
```

[This](http://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.construct.php) requests local time. But you want UTC time. [Specify](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.datetimezone.php) UTC as a second parameter to the constructor.